# How to save data from Firebase as a number with Vue.js

Tags: string, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, numbers

I use Firebase with Vue.js.
Here I save to the database with this command:

```
saveEvent(){
  db.collection('events').add({
    title: this.title,
    content: this.content,
    start: this.start,
    end: this.end,
    split: this.split,
  })
  this.events.push(this.data)
}
```

Everything is saved as string, but I would like to save 'split' as a number.

[image: Split is saved as a String]

do you have any suggestions for solutions?

Comment: try doing `split: Number(this.split)` maybe?

Comment: it can be so simple. thank you, that helped.

Comment: @doesnotmatter Can you post that as an answer, so we get closure on the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing `split: Number(this.split)` to cast a string into number.